# How can I remove a browser's cache server-side, using ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I remove a browser's cache server-side, using ASP.NET (C#)?

A coupon shows by itself (I believe it comes from cache as I did also browse for other apparel sites). It breaks my JavaScript as well as my server-side code, as I am using an UpdatePanel for Ajax, and it duplicates the UpdatePanel's ID. I have renamed the UpdatePanel's ID, but it makes no difference. It generates "Invalid view State" exception. The coupon name is "FastSave"

What I have tried:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: im trying for remove my client cache for some reasons

Comment: It would not be a very nice place to be, the Internets, if a remote server could execute this kind of operation on a local machine...

Comment: Reference your comment, "I beleive it comes from cache," have you checked to see if that's actually the case by using a tool to check the response and see where the cached data is coming from?

Answer (score 2):

you can stop cache like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now);
    Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

Comment: With the disclaimer that this is not going to "un-cache" anything if it's already cached anywhere else.

Comment: Actually there is a coupon shows by itself(I beleive it comes from cache as I did also browse for other apperel sites.),
breaks my javascript as well as server side code, as updatePanel is used for ajax, and it duplicates the UpdatePanel's ID.I have rename the updatePanel' ID.But it makes no diff. It generates "Invalid view State" exception.
Kindly help.

Comment: Please edit your question with that information--it does not help to have it in a comment on a single answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I set client-side browser caching in my ASP.NET MVC 2 app:

```
public class CacheFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the cache duration in seconds. The default is 10 seconds.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The cache duration in seconds.</value>

    public int Duration { get; set; }

    public CacheFilterAttribute() { Duration = 10; }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) {
        if (Duration <= 0) return;

        var cache = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
        var cacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Duration);

        cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
        cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.Add(cacheDuration));
        cache.SetMaxAge(cacheDuration);
        cache.AppendCacheExtension("must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
    }
}
```

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2008/03/28/asp-net-mvc-action-filter-caching-and-compression.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

You can tell the client not to cache something, but once it does there is no server side mechanism to clear the cache.  You have to wait for the cache to expire or the user to clear the cache.